# Stop Playing audio files on Open new fragment activity

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-fragmentactivity

I played an audio files on button click in fragment activity 1, when I open new fragment activity 2, audio is keep playing.
Here I want to stop playing audio when I open fragment activity 2.

```
public class tactics extends Fragment {
private MediaPlayer mp;


@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tactics, container, false);


    stopPlaying(); //when fragment tactics is open then audio file should be stoped.


    Button v0 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.v0);

    v0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            stopPlaying();
           mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(),R.raw.b2);
           mp.start();

        }
    });

    return v;

}
```

public void stopPlaying() {

```
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Call mp.stop() and mp.release() in your first activity onDestroy() callback

Comment: its working. Thanks bro

Comment: can I use private void instead of public void (android studio suggest)        will it effect my code or not

Comment: Yes you can. private void stopPlaying() only access in class

Answer (score 0):

Fragment life cycle would help you do that, onCreateView() of each fragment you can check the media player state and switch it off as per your requirement